# Angular2 NgFor Force Rerender on Event

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm changing an Angular Page, to load items on demand,.

It's a ngFor Code, inside another ngFor.
So the second ngFor has no data until it's parent is clicked.

This is the internal ngFor.

`<result #ResultComponent (click)="onContainerClick($event, i)" *ngFor="let result of resultItems; let  i = index" [result]="result" [index]="i"></result>`

and it's the TS Behind:

```
  onAfterResponse(data: any): void {        
    debugger;
    this.IsFetch= true;
    console.log("We got the data");
    console.log(data);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.resultItems = <Result[]>data.fullDisplayedResults;            
    })   


   };
```

But it doesn't refresh and ngFor data.
help?

Comment: What is the purpose of running that code using ngZone?

Comment: Did you try using ChangeDetectorRef?